# Why is App Engine throwing an error while getting one particular entity by its id?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, debugging, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

I am getting entities from App Engine's Datastore using the JDO method `PersistenceManager.getObjectbyId()` where `id` is the `Long` key automatically generated by App Engine when an entity is created.

The method runs fine for all entities except one particular entity where a strange exception is thrown:

"`java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Double`"

I double checked to confirm that the id of this entity is a valid Long value. Moreover, since `getObjectById()` is a standard JDO method, does this look like a bug in the App Engine's implementation of this method?

FYI, interestingly, the value of id of this particular entity is the highest among all the entities in my project's datastore.

Comment: It seems that one of the fields in the datastore entity does convert to type expected by the mapping library. Can you check the field types in class and the field types in the datastore (see admin console).

Comment: Thanks Peter! Unfortunately, I can't check the entity now since I deleted it and added back its data as a fresh entity. I guess this may have been the result of modifying the entity in the datastore viewer provided in the admin console which seems to mess up the entity fields for querying.

Comment: Yep, this could most likely be the case. If you saved entity as Long (e.g. 123) it would not be mapped to Double (e.g. 123.0)